# Better to allocate too much memory on the stack, or the correct amount on the heap?

Tags: memory, memory-management

I have just started learning rust, and it is my first proper look into a low level language (I do python, usually). Part of the tutorial explains that a string literal is stored on the stack, because it has a fixed (and known) size; it also explains that a non-initialised string is stored on the heap, so that its size can grow as necessary.

My understanding is that the stack is much faster than the heap. In the case of a string whose size is unknown, but I know it will not ever require more than n bytes, does it make sense to allocate space on the stack for the maximum size, instead of sticking it on the heap?

The purpose of this question is not to solve a problem, but to help me understand, so I would appreciate verbose and detailed answers!

Answer (score 0):

The difference in performance between the stack and the heap comes due to the fact that objects in the heap may change size at run time, and they must then be reallocated somewhere else in the heap.

Now for the verbose part. Imagine you have an integer i32. This number will always be the same size, so any modifications made to it will occur in place. When it goes out of scope (it stops being needed in the program) it will either be deleted, or, a more efficient solution, it will be deleted along with the whole stack it belongs to.

Now you want to create a String. So you create it in the heap and give it a value. And then you modify it and add some characters to it. Now two things can happen.

1. There is free memory after the string, so the allocator uses this memory to write the new part.
2. There already is an object allocated in the memory right after the string, and of course, you don't want to overwrite it. So the allocator looks for the next free memory space with enough size to hold the new string and copies into it that string. Then deletes the old one, freeing that memory.

As you can see in the heap the number of operations to be made is incredibly higher than in the stack, so its performance will be lower.

Now, in your case, there are some methods specifically for memory reservation. `String::reserve()` and `String::reserve_exact()`. I would recommend you to look at the documentation for Rust always. Usually there already is a std method for what you want.